# How to show convergence of $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{4^6}+...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show convergence of $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{4^6}+...$

I have found sum of this series but not able to prove convergence,

$1+\frac12 \left( 1+\frac14+\left( \frac14 \right)^2+ \dots \right)+\frac{1}{16} \left( 1+\frac{1}{16}+\left( \frac{1}{16} \right)^2+ \dots \right)=1+\frac12 \cdot \frac43+\frac{1}{16} \cdot \frac{16}{15}=1+\frac23+\frac{1}{15}={\frac{26}{15}}$.

If I write orginal sequence as $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^8}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^{12}}+...$

I can see this series is formed by removing and rearranging some elements of series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n} $.

What next?

Comment: "I have found sum of this series but not able to prove convergence".  When every term of the series is positive, you are permitted to rearrange the terms in any manner that you wish.  So, in this instance, finding the overall (finite) sum of the rearranged terms proves convergence.  Google : "rearrange terms in absolutely convergent infinite series".

Comment: My advice to you to tackle problems of this type is to write given series as $\sum a_n$, find a formula for $a_n$, and try to use results like comparison test, bounded convergence theorem, etc.

Comment: *"I have found sum of this series but not able to prove convergence"* If you have not yet proved that the sum of the series exists, how could you possibly have already found it?

Comment: @Sandejo Unfair question.  The OP (i.e. original poster) found the sum of the series only where the terms are rearranged.  The OP doesn't realize that this implies that he has found the sum of the terms of the original series, precisely because all of the terms are positive.  See my first comment.

Comment: @Sandejo i get what you are trying to say. Firstly we have to prove the existence In order to find the sum, but here I knew this series converges it's just that I was unable to show it, the sum part I have included is just so as i know this converges and has sum but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $a_n = \frac{1}{(3+(-1)^{n})^n} \le \frac{1}{2^n}$, so bound your series above with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is determining the exact value of the series by subdividing even and odd summands, thus obtaining two geometric series:

\begin{align*}
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{4^6}+...&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^5}\dots +1+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^6}+\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+ \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\\&=\frac{26}{15}.
\end{align*}

which is allowed as all terms are positive and the series converges.

Comment: But how do we know even before proving convergence that series does actually converge. Like that ramanujan's infinite sum of natural numbers $ 1+ 2+3+4 \dots=-1/12$

Comment: If you want to do it formally you can for example take the limit of the partial sums or you can use the root test.